# org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup specified

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

I am having this exception "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup specified". I had a ejb module project which is deployed on Glassfish Server. I am very confused with this exception since I think i had configured all the necessary configurations on my hibernate.cfg.xml. Here is my Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!-- DataSource properties (begin) -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">testdb</property>

<!-- JTA transaction properties (begin) -->
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup</property>

<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
```

This is the stack trace im encountering:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup specified
at org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:85)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
at dao.CourseDAO.insert(CourseDAO.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor407.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor458.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 121 more
```

Thanks. Hope you can help me .

Can anyone tell me what do i missed here. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the entire exception with stack trace.

Comment: <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>